# Magento2.4.6: After upgrade magento from 2.3.5 to magento2.4.6, getting this error "Attempt to read property "paymentMethods" on null"?

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, magento2.4.2, magento2.4.5, magento2.4.6

**I have upgraded my website from magento2.3.5 to magneto2.4.6, and everything works fine but when I open any order detail page that was placed before upgradation, it gives me this error, any idea?**
[image]

Comment: have you tried to upgrade module as well ?

Comment: i've got latest from git

Comment: if i place new order then it works fine order details page open, but for old orders that was placed before upgrade it shows this error

Answer (score 0):

Looks like custom module compatibility issue. Make sure StripeIntegration_Payments module is compatible with Magento 2.4.6. Reach out to the module developers with error details.

It's difficult to asses the issue without looking under the hood.